# Questions About Jeroboam (son of Nebat)'s "Festival...in Imitation of the Festival in Judah"

Tags: sukkot, melachim-kings-book-of, chronology

[1 Kings 12:26-33](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.12.26-33?lang=bi) records Jeroboam's religious "reforms." Among these were the establishment of a "festival...in imitation of the festival in Judah":

> 32 He stationed at Bethel the priests of the shrines that he had appointed to sacrifice to the calves that he had made. And Jeroboam established a festival on the fifteenth day of the eighth month; in imitation of the festival in Judah, he established one at Bethel, and he ascended the altar [there]. 33 On the fifteenth day of the eighth month—the month in which he had contrived of his own mind to establish a festival for the Israelites—Jeroboam ascended the altar that he had made in Bethel.
> As he ascended the altar to present an offering...

Commentators, such as [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.12.33?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), view Sukkot, which was to be held on the fifteenth day of the seventh month, as the imitated festival. Jeroboam's one-month shift intrigues me:

1. Is this "imitation-Sukkot" the only festival that Israel continued to practice after the split with Judah?
2. If not, how did this shift affect the other festivals? Were they too pushed forward by a month, resulting in an overall calendar shift (as proposed in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1515658#metadata_info_tab_contents)), or did Jeroboam allow them to be followed at their proper time?